# VBA code to add asterik before and after bold text in Ms word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have an entire paragraph in Ms word with some few BOld letters in it..I'm looking for any vba code to add ** before and after each bold letter and move to next..untill every bold letter is been formateed with double asterik before and after.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  It'll place a set of double asterik before and after each bold letter for the entire document:

```
Sub InsertAsteriks()
  Dim doc As Document
  Set doc = ActiveDocument

  Dim prev As Boolean: prev = False

  For i = doc.Range.Characters.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
     If doc.Range.Characters(i).Bold Then
       doc.Range.Characters(i).InsertAfter "**"
       prev = True
     Else
       If prev Then
         doc.Range.Characters(i).InsertAfter "**"
         prev = False
       End If
     End If
  Next

  If prev Then
    doc.Range.Characters(1).InsertBefore "**"
  End If

End Sub
```

Alternatively if you only want this action to be performed on text that you highlight you can use this instead:

```
Sub InsertAsteriks2()
  Dim prev As Boolean: prev = False

  With Selection
    For i = .Characters.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
      If .Characters(i).Bold Then
        .Characters(i).InsertAfter "**"
        prev = True
      Else
        If prev Then
          .Characters(i).InsertAfter "**"
          prev = False
        End If
      End If
    Next

    If prev Then
      .InsertBefore "**"
    End If

  End With
End Sub
```